# Laravel Authentication for both primary and sub domain plus redirect on sub domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am trying to set a different Authentication for my sub domain, e.g. if the user is a guest and accessing the domain via sub domain I want to redirect them to the sub domain log in and if a user is accessing from the primary domain page I want to redirect them to the primary domain login page.
**Primary domain**

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::get('/profile', array(
        'as' => 'profile-user',
        'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
     ));

  });
```

URL: example.com/account

So if someone was to access this without logging in they will be redirected to the login page for the primary domain which by default Laravel does it in the filter BUT this doesn't seem to work for sub domains

**SUB DOMAIN**

```
 Route::group(['domain' => 'dev.example.com'], function() {

    Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::group(array('before' => 'my account'), function() {
    Route::get('/mysub/account', array(
        'as' => 'sub-account',
        'uses' => 'AccountController@subAccount'

        ));
    });
  });
});
```

URL: *dev.example.com/mysub/account*

so if someone was to access the above URL without logging in they should be redirected to *dev.example.com* which is the home page for my sub domain

The "auth" filter doesn't work for subdomains do in the config/session.php i have tried **'domain' => '.example.com',** and '**domain' => '*example.com',** but that doesn't seem to do the job plus it completely stopped loggin in from the primary domain

For the redirect if the Authentication failed from the sub domain, I tried

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        elseif (Request::getHost() == 'dev.example.com') {

            return Redirect::guest(URL::route('subdomain-login'));
        }

        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest(URL::route('primary-domain-login'));
        }
    }
});
```

but this seems to redirect them back "subdomain-login" even if the log in is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that the best solution for this was to create another auth filter for the sub domain.

```
Route::filter('subauth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }

        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest(URL::route('login'));
        }
    }
});
```